# Assigning users to a conference. Problem with string to collection type mismatch

Tags: java, html, spring

I have an application in which I am trying to assign users to a conference. When submitted though, it passes as a string and I receive an error for type mismatch.

My controller methods:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/assign/{id}")
public String showStudentAssignForm(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id, Model model){
    Optional<Conference> conference = conferenceService.findById(id);
    List<User> userList = userService.findAllByRoles("ROLE_STUDENT");
    model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
    model.addAttribute("conference", conference.get());
    return "assignStudent";
}

@PostMapping(path = "/assign/save")
public String saveAssignedUsers(ConferenceDto conference){
    conferenceService.updateConference(conference);
    return "redirect:/teacher/configure";
}
```

In my controllerDto I have:

```
private Collection<User> students;
```

In the html I have:

```
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Users: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
                    <th:block th:each="user : ${userList}">
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{students}" th:text="${user.name}" th:value="${user}" class="m-2" />
                        </div>
                    </th:block>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It's supposed to pass selected users and store it as a collection although they are passed as string. I get the following error:

```
Field error in object 'conferenceDto' on field 'students': rejected value [Bill Gates,Test McTest]; codes [typeMismatch.conferenceDto.students,typeMismatch.students,typeMismatch.java.util.Collection,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [conferenceDto.students,students]; arguments []; default message [students]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.Collection' for property 'students'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model.User' for property 'students[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this issue? Am I supposed to make a converter (if so how can I implement it in my controller?) or can I go around this another way? Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seemed to revolve around having the string mismatch with collection and/or user. I solved this issue by changing `private Collection<User> students;` to `private Collection<String> students;` in my conferenceDto and then when saving in my ConferenceService class I add to the conference(model object, not the Dto) the list of users which I find with *findByName* or *findById* from the string in the conferenceDto.